# Does Orisa's Supercharge ultimate stack with other damage buffs?

Tags: overwatch

Orisa's ultimate is a damage boost to all allied heroes in line of sight. Does this stack at all with other boosts such as Mercy's right click or with Ana's nano-boost or can all 3 stack together?

Comment: I don't see any reason for it not to, but Orisa hype let's goooo

Comment: Is she even released to the PTR yet? If not, technically all of these Orisa questions are off-topic, at least for a few days.

Comment: She is on PTR yes, there is lots of gameplay footage out already.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. I'm at work so I can't check any of that stuff yet, and getting news from Arqade is... inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

There used to be a [PTR bug](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753187460) where Mercy's damage boost didn't stack with the Supercharger, but it was fixed before the move to live.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, They can all stack on each other, Super soldier 76 incoming.

Comment: Do you have anything you can use to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Blizzard will announce in their patch note if there is a cap(for example, Bastion has a cap on damage reduction).